# Manipulation with arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

After long work with R I returned to work with Python and find that array maniputation is not very convenient. Arrays cannot be indexed by row and column names. I hope that someone can help and show me how to manipulate with arrays in a Pythonic way.

I have two `numpy` arrays

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

b = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5).T + 10
>>> b
array([[10, 15, 20, 25],
       [11, 16, 21, 26],
       [12, 17, 22, 27],
       [13, 18, 23, 28],
       [14, 19, 24, 29]])
```

and row names of each array

```
a_rownames = ["m1", "m2", "m3"]
b_rownames = ["m1", "m2", "m1", "m3", "m2"]
```

The task is to replace values of specified columns `columns_ids` in array `b` with corresponding values from `a`. The order of columns in both arrays `a` and `b` is the same.

```
columns_ids = [False, True, False, True]
```

The expected output:

```
array([[10,  1, 20,  3],
       [11,  5, 21,  7],
       [12,  1, 22,  3],
       [13,  9, 23, 11],
       [14,  5, 24,  7]])
```

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Note that you don't actually need named columns to do this, but numpy does support named columns (see documentation for dtype) and pandas' dataframe is specifically meant to mirror usage you are used to in R.

Comment: I looked at `pandas` description and it looks like what I need to easily migrate from R to Python world. Thanks for pointing me out! But if this is possible to do with numpy this will be also nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you abandon names for a moment, this isn't too hard:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
b = numpy.arange(20).reshape(4,5).T + 10

b_rows = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1]
columns_ids = numpy.array([False, True, False, True])

b[:, columns_ids] = a[:, columns_ids][b_rows]

b
#>>> array([[10,  1, 20,  3],
#>>>        [11,  5, 21,  7],
#>>>        [12,  1, 22,  3],
#>>>        [13,  9, 23, 11],
#>>>        [14,  5, 24,  7]])
```

If you really want an external array of names:

```
a = numpy.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
b = numpy.arange(20).reshape(4,5).T + 10

a_rownames = numpy.array(["m1", "m2", "m3"])
b_rownames = numpy.array(["m1", "m2", "m1", "m3", "m2"])

_, b_rows = numpy.where(a_rownames == b_rownames[:, numpy.newaxis])

b[:, columns_ids] = a[:, columns_ids][b_rows]

b
#>>> array([[10,  1, 20,  3],
#>>>        [11,  5, 21,  7],
#>>>        [12,  1, 22,  3],
#>>>        [13,  9, 23, 11],
#>>>        [14,  5, 24,  7]])
```

---

This piece of magic has three steps:

```
_, b_rows = numpy.where(a_rownames == b_rownames[:, numpy.newaxis])
```

First, we generate two perpendicular arrays:

```
a_rownames
#>>> array(['m1', 'm2', 'm3'],
#>>>       dtype='<U2')

b_rownames[:, numpy.newaxis]
#>>> array([['m1'],
#>>>        ['m2'],
#>>>        ['m1'],
#>>>        ['m3'],
#>>>        ['m2']],
#>>>       dtype='<U2')
```

Then our `==` comparison will use "broadcasting" to repeat these arrays until the dimensions match:

```
a_rownames == b_rownames[:, numpy.newaxis]
#>>> array([[ True, False, False],
#>>>        [False,  True, False],
#>>>        [ True, False, False],
#>>>        [False, False,  True],
#>>>        [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`numpy.where` gives the `xs` and `ys` to index this array to get all the `True` values. We're only interested in the `ys`, so we ignore the `xs`.

```
_, b_rows = numpy.where(a_rownames == b_rownames[:, numpy.newaxis])
```

---

The other piece of magic:

```
b[:, columns_ids] = a[:, columns_ids][b_rows]
```

Requires knowing two different types of indexing:

- indexing with boolean arrays *filters* the array
- indexing with integer arrays gets the rows at those indexes

Indexing like

```
array[xs]
```

or

```
array[xs, :]
```

(they're the same due to broadcasting) will give you all the indexes that match due to the rules above, filtered in the first axis.

Using

```
array[:, ys]
```

will filter in the second axis.

So first we filter the columns (second axis)

```
b[:, columns_ids]
#>>> array([[ 1,  3],
#>>>        [ 5,  7],
#>>>        [ 1,  3],
#>>>        [ 9, 11],
#>>>        [ 5,  7]])

a[:, columns_ids]
#>>> array([[ 1,  3],
#>>>        [ 5,  7],
#>>>        [ 9, 11]])
```

Then we filter the rows on `a` (first axis):

```
a[:, columns_ids][b_rows]
#>>> array([[ 1,  3],
#>>>        [ 5,  7],
#>>>        [ 1,  3],
#>>>        [ 9, 11],
#>>>        [ 5,  7]])
```

They are now the same shape, so you can do slice assignment:

```
b[:, columns_ids] = a[:, columns_ids][b_rows]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or to produce a new array without over-writing the original in b:

```
np.where(column_ids[None,:], a[row_ids], b)
```

where column_ids and row_ids are also arrays as in the other answer.

Comment: This is also very nice and extremely short solution! But what was a reason to use `None` to create newaxis? It works fine even with `np.where(columns_ids, a[b_rows], b)`

Comment: I find it useful to be explicit about the dimensions of the arrays being handled.